# In Python with Matplotlib how to check if a subplot is empty in the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, figure, subplot

I have some graphs created with `NetworkX` and show them on screen using `Matplotlib`. Specifically, since I don't know in advance how many graphs I need to show, I create a `subplot` on the figure on fly. That works fine. However, at some point in the script, some `subplots` are removed from the figure and the figure is shown with some **empty** subplots. I would like to avoid it, but I was not able to retrieve the subplots that are empty in the figure. Here is my code:

```
#instantiate a figure with size 12x12
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

#when a graph is created, also a subplot is created:
ax = plt.subplot(3,4,count+1)

#and the graph is drawn inside it: N.B.: pe is the graph to be shown
nx.draw(pe, positions, labels=positions, font_size=8, font_weight='bold', node_color='yellow', alpha=0.5)

#many of them are created..

#under some conditions a subplot needs to be deleted, and so..
#condition here....and then retrieve the subplot to deleted. The graph contains the id of the ax in which it is shown.
for ax in fig.axes:
    if id(ax) == G.node[shape]['idax']:
         fig.delaxes(ax)
```

until here works fine, but when I show the figure, the result looks like this:

[image]

you can notice that there are two empty subplots there.. at the second position and at the fifth. How can I avoid it? Or.. how can I re-organize the subplots in such a way that there are no more blanks in the figure?

Any help is apreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to do this I would keep a list of axes and when I delete the contents of one I would swap it out with a full one. I think the example below solved the problem (or at least gives an idea of how to solve it):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this is just a helper class to keep things clean
class MyAxis(object):
    def __init__(self,ax,fig):
        # this flag tells me if there is a plot in these axes
        self.empty = False
        self.ax = ax
        self.fig = fig
        self.pos = self.ax.get_position()

    def del_ax(self):
        # delete the axes
        self.empty = True
        self.fig.delaxes(self.ax)

    def swap(self,other):
        # swap the positions of two axes
        #
        # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT!
        #
        new_pos = other.ax.get_position()
        self.ax.set_position(new_pos)
        other.ax.set_position(self.pos)
        self.pos = new_pos

def main():
    # generate a figure and 10 subplots in a grid
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5,nrows=2)

    # get these as a list of MyAxis objects
    my_axes = [MyAxis(ax,fig) for ax in axes.ravel()]

    for ax in my_axes:
        # plot some random stuff
        ax.ax.plot(range(10))

    # delete a couple of axes
    my_axes[0].del_ax()
    my_axes[6].del_ax()

    # count how many axes are dead
    dead = sum([ax.empty for ax in my_axes])

    # swap the dead plots for full plots in a row wise fashion
    for kk in range(dead):
        for ii,ax1 in enumerate(my_axes[kk:]):
            if ax1.empty:
                print ii,"dead"
                for jj,ax2 in enumerate(my_axes[::-1][kk:]):
                    if not ax2.empty:
                        print "replace with",jj
                        ax1.swap(ax2)
                        break
                break



    plt.draw()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The extremely ugly for loop construct is really just a placeholder to give an example of how the axes can be swapped.

Comment: thank you for this hint, I will re-elaborate my script.

Comment: I couldn't get `dead` to work on matplotlib 2.1.1. However  i found the `has_data()` method can be used as a work around.  i.e. `dead = len(my_axes) -sum([ax.has_data() for ax in fig.my_axes])